# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'Sphinx==1.8.5' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: pip, python-sphinx

When I try `sphinx-build --version`, this error popup:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)                                 
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'Sphinx==1.8.5' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U install sphinx from both system-package-managemetn(e.g., apt) and pip. Just remove system-wise sphinx.